# Draw boxes of fixed size into the full height of a table cell with CSS

Tags: css

I would like to use CSS to draw two boxes (red and green) of a certain size into a table cell. I can't get them to fill the full height of the table cell.

This is what I have so far:

```css
td {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 5px;
}

td.boxes {
  padding: 0
}

div.a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3px;
  background-color: red;
}

div.b {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Mj</td>
    <td class="boxes">
      <div class="a">&nbsp;</div><!--
      --><div class="b">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `tr` & `td.boxes` element to `display: flex` and child `div` heights to `100%`.

```
td.boxes,
tr {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zx5Lvzym/

Answer (score -1):

Use a gradient. the percents tell how far to color with each color. Thus 50% means up to the halfway point, and 51% means 51 onwards.

```css
td {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 5px;
}

td.boxes {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, green 51%);
  padding: 0
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Mj</td>
    <td class="boxes">
      Example Text Here
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: While this answer doesn't help me (by _two_ boxes I actually meant two elements) I understand that that wasn't really clear from my question. Anyway, the border between red and green is also blurry, which makes this a bad answer.